# Error al tratar de crear usuario en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero crear un usuario en phpmyadmin pero me genera el siguiente error `Error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" desde el manejador de la tabla Aria`

[image: Esto me sale al seleccionar privilegios]

Comment: Pudieras mostrar por favor la consulta que llevas a cabo para crear el nuevo usuario?

Comment: No estoy utilizando una consulta, quiero hacerlo de forma grafica

Comment: Ese error fue [reportado como un bug en enero de 2019](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18341). Por ahora, no respuesta, no comentarios, no nada... Intenta crear el usuario mediante [`CREATE USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html), que para eso existe.

Comment: para este error solo deben seleccionar todas las tablas de la base de datos "MySql" y posteriormente darle a repara, a mi me funciono.

Answer (score 2):

Al Editar los privilegios de la cuenta de usuario, desactiva la opción 'Grant' justo debajo de la sección 'Administración'.

Comment: Puedes ayudar a tu respuesta con mayores detalles para que sirva a otras personas.